# How to shuffle, slice and then reorder an array in php?

Tags: php, shuffle, slice

The code works until I try to order the slice with the asort function, I then just get a blank page when I run this. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$arange = range( 1 , 80, 1);

shuffle($arange);

$shufl = array_slice($arange,  0, 5);

$sortshufl = asort($shufl, SORT_NUMERIC);


foreach ($sortshufl as $number) {

    echo "$number ";
}

?>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting and set it to E_ALL, that should tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asort()` sorts the array in place and returns a boolean, so your result is in `$shufl`.

```
foreach( $shufl as $number ) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Enable PHP error reporting and you'll avoid the blank pages on errors.

Answer (score 4):

`asort` returns a boolean, not the sorted array. And it's meant for associative arrays.

Use the plain [`sort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function (also returns a boolean, sorts the array "in place").

```
sort($shufl, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ($shufl as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you both, I have error reporting enabled now, and my code is fixed :)